# What is the correct implementation of the dice coefficient?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-function, semantic-segmentation

What is the correct implementation of the dice coefficient?

This code

```py
def dice_coef1(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
  intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=[1,2,3])
  union = K.sum(y_true, axis=[1,2,3]) + K.sum(y_pred, axis=[1,2,3])
  dice = K.mean((2. * intersection + smooth)/(union + smooth), axis=0)
  return dice
```

gives me 0.85, while this code

```py
def dice_coef2(target, prediction, smooth=1):
    numerator = 2.0 * K.sum(target * prediction) + smooth
    denominator = K.sum(target) + K.sum(prediction) + smooth
    coef = numerator / denominator
    return coef
```

gives me 0.94.

Answer (score 0):

I isolated the functions and for me they produce the same results. This means the overall mathematics are correct. So you might want to look into your data or the selection of your axis in  `dice_coef1`. Without your dataset I cant reproduce your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll say that the first one is the right one, because you want to have the mean dice by sample which is complete different to the dice value of the entire database.